# Descending sorting by rows index data frame Shiny

Tags: r, sorting, shiny

I'm using RenderDataTable to display data frame.
Using `order = list(list(column_number, 'desc'))` works for any column except the index. 
I would like to sort by descending order in order to see the newest entries at the top. Using `0` doesn't work in RenderDataTable. Any idea to force the descending sorting in options list? The default is always ascending order by index.

Here is my attempt:

```
    DT::datatable(reporting[],
                  options = list(
                    lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200),
                    order = list(list(0, 'desc')),
                    pageLength = 25
                  ))
```

Comment: why not ordering your `reporting[]` data.frame?

Comment: this is actually inside a if statement when action button equals to 0, otherwise I call a function `reporting_update()` in place of `reporting[]`. And this function gets data from SQLite DB. I would have to sort rowid of the DB. It seems easier to sort here at the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `order = DT[order(as.numeric(rownames(DT)),decreasing = TRUE)]` which should order your data in descending order. Although, it is hard to replicate your problem without the data. Here is a working example I was able to produce:

`DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)`

`DT`

```
 x y v
1: b 1 1
2: b 3 2
3: b 6 3
4: a 1 4
5: a 3 5
6: a 6 6
7: c 1 7
8: c 3 8
9: c 6 9
```

`DT[order(as.numeric(rownames(DT)),decreasing = TRUE)]`

```
x y v
1: c 6 9
2: c 3 8
3: c 1 7
4: a 6 6
5: a 3 5
6: a 1 4
7: b 6 3
8: b 3 2
9: b 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I had to add a comma for some reason `DT[order(as.numeric(rownames(DT)),decreasing = TRUE), ]`to work around the error `undefined columns selected order`